# TFS Incremental build error - Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally

Tags: tfs, msbuild, incremental-build

I'm trying to enable incremental build of my VS solution. In the GUI for xaml build process template, I set `"Clean Workspace"` to `"None"` and added `/p:IncrementalBuild=True` as an MSBuild argument. I then checked in changes to a file, but when I run my TFS build, I immediately get the following error:

```
Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally

Exception Message: One or more errors occurred while performing a Get operation. (type GetException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.SyncWorkspaceInternal.ThrowIfErrorsOccurred.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I believe TFS gets my file but cannot overwrite the existing file on the build agent and errors out. How can I force it to overwrite the file?

Comment: Can you check, if the file is open or is in use by another process.

Comment: Is that file changed by the build process?

Comment: the file is not in use and not changed

Comment: We see this error sometimes. It's intermittent. The TFS incremental build option is extremely flaky.

Answer (score 6):

The file is writable. When there's a writable file, get will not overwrite it unless the /overwrite option is used. However, you would need to figure out how the file is becoming writable. You may want to go back to the default option of creating a new workspace, running a build with verbose logs, and see what is making the file writable.

Comment: Shouldn't he just simply use the `/overwrite` parameter? `/force`also implies the `/all` parameter, which overwrites all files, not just the writable ones?

Comment: Also, do you by any chance know if that is possible in build vNext?

Comment: You are correct. I've updated my answer to say overwrite. Do you mean if it is possible to specify /overwrite?

Comment: Yes, the step with getting the source code, does not appear to be very configurable.

Comment: I asked, and the answer depends on the version of the build agent in build vnext. The original build vnext agent (1.x) does not provide a way to control whether /overwrite is included. The new agent (2.x) does specify /overwrite every time in order to prevent writable files causing problems. The new agent will be the default in TFS "15" and in VS Team Services.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML Build, you can add a GetOptions input for the SyncWorkspace activity.

        `<mtbwa:SyncWorkspace _locID="Activity037" _locAttrData="DisplayName" DisplayName="Get Workspace" VersionOverride="[GetVersion]" Workspace="[Workspace]" GetOptions="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions.Overwrite]">`

See DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml as a go-by.

TfvcTemplate.12.xaml doesn't expose a way to do it.