# TFS 2013: Automerge doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I've to make a merge between our trunk to the branch, and we have a LOT of modified files.

Mosts of the changes are not conflicting, but currently, when I try to merge the branch, I've a lot of files which could be automatically solved.

I've a button "AutoMerge", but when I click on it, it just open the same tool that if I click on "Merge changes In Merge Tool".

Also, when I'm in this tool, if I click on "Next Conflict", I've none, and I can directly click on "Accept Merge".

I tried to do an AutoResolve all, but it says me "No conflict has been resolved due to conflicting content changes, name changes or encoding changes. These conflicts will need to be resolved individually".

So any idea on why/how to solve all those non conflictings files would me more than welcome since I've more than 800 files to review otherwise.

Thank you very much

I don't know if it impact something, but we currently have Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2010.

Comment: same issue here with VS 2015 and TFS 2013

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. In my case, my output was giving the message "Unable to peform the get operation because the file already exists locally" for each file after I did a get. I searched regarding that problem and found [TFS Incremental build error - Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050654/tfs-incremental-build-error-unable-to-perform-the-get-operation-because-the-fi).

My project folder was no longer set to read-only because of messing around with a different problem, which led to this problem. I ended up doing a full overwrite get for all files (Right-click --> Advanced --> Get Specific Version, choose Latest Version and check "overwrite all files") and it resolved my issue. It is probably not the solution for all cases, but something worth checking.