# TFS 2015 vNext build fails with error Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

During our incremental builds, where the repository clean parameter is set to 'false'. Build fails intermittently during get source step with the following error: Unable to perform the get operation because the file already exists locally.

Is there a way to resolve the error without setting the repository clean parameter to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Buck Hodges (Director of Engineering at Microsoft) has given the answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050654/tfs-incremental-build-error-unable-to-perform-the-get-operation-because-the-fi):

> The file is writable. When there's a writable file, get will not
>   overwrite it unless the /overwrite option is used. However, you would
>   need to figure out how the file is becoming writable. You may want to
>   go back to the default option of creating a new workspace, running a
>   build with verbose logs, and see what is making the file writable.
>
> Build vnext agent (1.x) does not provide a way to control whether
>   /overwrite is included. The new agent (2.x) does specify /overwrite
>   every time in order to prevent writable files causing problems. The
>   new agent will be the default in TFS "15" and in VS Team Services.

Comment: I just wanted to give a shout-out that this answer solved a problem I was having with TFS 2015. Thanks, Cece!