# A non version controlled file or writable file by the same name already exists locally

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

Trying to get latest version of the project and tfs and always get te same warning without the way of resolving conflict:
[When i click the file to resolve it gives me no options to choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tun3k.png)

Is there any way to get this around without resorting to cloning whole solution again?
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

For this kind error usually due to the file is writable. Take a look at @Buck Hodges (Director of Engineering at Microsoft)'s reply in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050654/tfs-incremental-build-error-unable-to-perform-the-get-operation-because-the-fi):

> The file is writable. When there's a writable file, get will not
>   overwrite it unless the /overwrite option is used. However, you would
>   need to figure out how the file is becoming writable. You may want to
>   go back to the default option of creating a new workspace, and see what is making the file writable.

By default, **the system does not retrieve an item if it is writable** (that is, if its read-only attribute is cleared) on the client machine. This option overrides the default behavior and overwrites a writable item, unless the item is checked out.

Instead get files directly through Visual Studio. You could try to get files through tf get command line and with `/overwrite` option. This should do the trick.

Comment: If you don't care about the file and just want to overwrite it, right-click on the folder you want to get, go to the advanced menu (last in VS 2019), select get specific version and click on the two overwrite options, this should fix up you problem